# Integrating Cypress with cucumber is failing

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I created a simple Cypress project to automate a website and it was working. Now I am trying to convert it into a cucumber Project and when executing the test cases, I am getting below error:

```
Running:  Features/shopping.feature                                                       (1 of 1)
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of C:\Users\001ZGA744\Personal\Cypress\Cucumber\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.


  1) An uncaught error was detected outside of a test

  0 passing (941ms)
  1 failing

  1) An uncaught error was detected outside of a test:
     TypeError: The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

  > (0 , _typeof4.default) is not a function

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code it will automatically fail the current test.

Cypress could not associate this error to any specific test.

We dynamically generated a new test to display this failure.
      at _typeof2 (http://localhost:60964/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration\Features\shopping.feature:303:63)
      at _typeof (http://localhost:60964/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration\Features\shopping.feature:317:39)
      at eval (http://localhost:60964/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration\Features\shopping.feature:23486:2332)
      at Object.eval (http://localhost:60964/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration\Features\shopping.feature:32935:14)
      at Object.eval (http://localhost:60964/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration\Features\shopping.feature:32937:4)
      at Object.254.C:\Users\001ZGA744\Personal\Cypress\Cucumber\node_modules\@babel\runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault (http://localhost:60964/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration\Features\shopping.feature:32937:17)
      at o (http://localhost:60964/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration\Features\shopping.feature:1:265)
      at eval (http://localhost:60964/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration\Features\shopping.feature:1:316)
      at Object.169.babel-runtime/helpers/classCallCheck (http://localhost:60964/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration\Features\shopping.feature:9432:15)
      at o (http://localhost:60964/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\integration\Features\shopping.feature:1:265)
```

This is how my Project Structure looks like:
[image]

I am unable to understand the reason of the issue.
Please suggest.

Comment: To write the tests with cucumber and cypress, you can follow [this](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/cytorus/blob/master/docs/1.GettingStarted.md) easy guide.

Answer (score 0):

Please remember you need a stepDefinitions folder at least. And then, in the package.json file you should declare the Cypress Cucumber Preprocessor Style pattern.

Something like this:

"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
"nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true
}

Or:

"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
"commonPath": "common",
"stepDefinitions": "step_definitions"
}

Depending on what you choose.